# Using Case Statements with Not Exists as Part of Where Clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm calculating the depreciation of vehicles and need to grab the previous month's values if it exists.

I've written a case statement in the where clause to see if the value exists. If it does, then I want to subtract one month and use that value to get the previous months data. If it does not exist then I want the current month's data. But it'll only do one or the other. Am I messing up where the exists is?

```
SELECT b.*
--this is month we want to compare (For example month 45)
FROM #changes AS a 
--this has all the months  (for example month 1-50)
INNER JOIN work.dbo.DepreciationSchedule AS b 
    ON b.VehicleID = a.VehicleID
--If the previous months value exists in table b (Ex month 44), then take take that months value otherwise take the current value of table a (Ex month 45)
WHERE b.Month = CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                 FROM #changes AS innerA 
                                 WHERE innerA.month = a.month - 1) 
                    THEN a.Month - 1  
                    ELSE a.Month 
                END
```

Comment: Give us your actual result and your expected result.

Comment: In your case statement you are only checking where a record exists for the month being tested, but you're not matching it with a vehicle don't you also want `innerA.VehicleID = a.VehicleID`

Comment: I am not sure about this where condition you have innerA.month = a.month - 1 sample data and expected results would help. as you may have data from previous month in A and current month in innera is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There were two things that I had to change.

1. Add the vehicle ID to the current subquery to make sure that I only wanted those vehicles in the temp table
2. Change the subquery table to the depreciation schedule

   Select b.*
       --this is month we want to compare (For example month 45)
       From #changes As a 
       --this has all the months  (for example month 1-50)
       Inner Join work.dbo.DepreciationSchedule As b 
       On b.VehicleID = a.VehicleID
       --If the previous months value exists in table b (Ex month 44), then take take that months value otherwise take the current value of table a (Ex month 45)
       Where b.Month = Case When  Exists (Select * From work.dbo.DepreciationSchedule As innerA Where innerA.month = a.month - 1 and innerA.VehicleID = a.vehicleID) Then a.Month -1  Else a.Month end